# Error deploying with heroku - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: heroku, deployment, build, module

thanks for helping out.

My app works in localhost but I got below "unexpected token" error after deploying to Heroku. Also, I have the error regarding "favicon.ico" . Heroku log is as follow:

```
2022-05-02T05:47:55.619466+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2022-05-02T05:47:56.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053439+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app.js:49
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053452+00:00 app[web.1]: return <div>
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053452+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053453+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053453+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053453+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053454+00:00 app[web.1]: at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053455+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053455+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053456+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053456+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053456+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
2022-05-02T05:47:57.053457+00:00 app[web.1]: at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
2022-05-02T05:47:57.178016+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-05-02T05:47:57.240533+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-02T05:48:51.164272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-tundra-48558.herokuapp.com request_id=b06ff127-684c-407c-a44c-5f2b70ed2506 fwd="1.36.26.158" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-02T05:48:53.759984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secure-tundra-48558.herokuapp.com request_id=2fd354ff-fc47-442b-812b-050147dd4c63 fwd="1.36.26.158" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

**Line 49 error in app.js is referring to below:**

```
  const Weather = () => {
      return <div>           <---- this line 49 with error

          <div class="heading col-md-9">
              <h5>Weather information for {weather.city}</h5>
              <hr></hr>
          </div>

          <div className="welements col-md-9">

              <div className="welement">
                  <strong>Weather :</strong> {weather.descp}
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Temperature :</strong> {C.toFixed(2)} &#8451;
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Humidity : </strong>{weather.humidity} %
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Pressure :</strong>  {weather.press} mb
              </div>


          </div>
      </div>



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you created the Procfile?
if not then:

you need to do the following on your bash console

```
    >cd <project directory>
    >touch Procfile
    >open Procfile
```

once you are in the procfile you need to add only single line in it

> web: node app.js (or whatever is you index file)

after doing this, try again with the process

```
    >git add .
    >git commit -m "you message"
    >git push heroku main
```

*PS: also make sure your app.js is in the root directory*

add a pair of ()

```
    const Weather = () => {
      return (<div>           

          <div class="heading col-md-9">
              <h5>Weather information for {weather.city}</h5>
              <hr></hr>
          </div>

          <div className="welements col-md-9">

              <div className="welement">
                  <strong>Weather :</strong> {weather.descp}
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Temperature :</strong> {C.toFixed(2)} &#8451;
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Humidity : </strong>{weather.humidity} %
              </div>
              <div className="welement">
                <strong>Pressure :</strong>  {weather.press} mb
              </div>


          </div>
      </div>);


  }
```

Comment: Hi Shivam, thanks for reply. Yes I have already created the Procfile too but still got error. May I please ask does "root" directory mean same level as the package.json? Since currently my app.js is in src folder. The src folder is at same level as package.json.

Comment: yes, same level as the package.json

Comment: you can pull out the app.js out, but make sure to update the routes everywhere.

Comment: Hi Shivam, thanks very much for help! I am now able to build successfully and deploy to heroku. However, after i view the heroku log, i noticed there is syntax error & something about favicon.ico. I have edited my 1st post to show error. Do you know how to fix that please?

Comment: I would request you to revert the changes in the question as my above answer is for that question accordingly, and if there is another issue post another question, as it helps other who are facing the same issue

Comment: also if you find my answer to be helpful and solution to your problem, plz do mark the solution as correct

Comment: btw you need to wrap your html inside () after return statement, i have updated the solution above

Comment: Thanks Shivam for the tip since I am newbie here =/. I have marked your solution as correct in above for the 1st question. Unfortunately for my 2nd question regarding the line 49, i still get same error after wrapping html in ( ). But maybe i'll open a new post for that, thanks for help!